# Is there a specific word for pen maker?

Tags: professions

I have searched but all I can find is "pen maker" for someone who makes pens. Is there an alternative like "cobbler" for someone who makes shoes?

Comment: There's unlikely to be a word for this, because it wasn't traditionally a separate profession: every scribe made his own pens.

Comment: I think "goose" is probably the word you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In an [article published by the Pen Makers Guild](http://www.penmakersguild.com/articles/roadtest_junejuly.pdf) I found this succinct  definition of *penturner:*

> One such group of craftsmen, **penturners**—so called for their ability to fashion pen caps and barrels on jewelers’ lathes—are creating unique handmade pens one piece at a time.

Comment: Except that's a recent hobbyist invention, and it only applies to pens with hand-turned wooden (or ivory, etc) shells.

Comment: @HotLicks - Perhaps so. But the OP only asked what such a person is called; they did not specify that the designation had to be a long-standing or traditional term.

Comment: But it could just as well be "quill-sharpener".

Comment: @HotLicks - Yes — if that's all they do when they manufacture a pen.  :)